# How to install ipsolver in python 3.6 on Windows 10

Tags: python

I'm going to do optimization using trust region interior point optimization.So I followed the steps mentioned in [here](https://github.com/antonior92/ip-nonlinear-solver)

But while running the below code given in link

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from ipsolver import minimize_constrained, NonlinearConstraint, BoxConstraint
```

I'm getting error message as

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ipsolver._large_scale_constrained'
```

Can you please guide me to resolve the issue?

Comment: Running *what* code?

Comment: updated in my original post

Comment: No repro.  After cloning the repo, running `setup.py install` etc, I copied the test code into a file in the repo's folder and run it with `python test.py`. I got `[1.95282196 0.08865598]`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos,which file, in repo,  are you referring as test code?